# Swift drag two views on VC

Tags: ios, swift

If some one please can point me in the right direction. 
I have two views in the same view controller and i what  that the user can drag up the lower view and make it bigger and the second one smaller.

[image]

[image]

Comment: And your question is?

Comment: i what to split the view controller in to two and the user can drag so he can make top part bigger or smaller. how can i change the height of UIview by dragging ?

Comment: Checkout https://github.com/twodayslate/SplitView

Answer (score 0):

On the Mac you'd use a split view. To my knowledge iOS's `UISplitViewController` isn't resizable, but you could try [MGSplitViewController](https://github.com/mattgemmell/MGSplitViewController) or some other open source variant.

Comment: It should be two UIview. the end result is like  Notification Center pull down but on a split screen

Comment: A split view would still work. "Closed" is "zero height".